# TeX Live 2023 Windows 10 - custom truetype font (Chevara) for use with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, texlive, windows, installing-fonts

I have only recently installed Tex Live and the attempts to install a TrueType font are based on [Using TrueType fonts with TeX (LaTeX) and pdfTeX (pdfLaTeX)](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm) and [Installing TeX fonts](https://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html)

What I have done:

1. Download font [here](https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Chevara-Normal)
2. extract and rename it to chevara.ttf
3. Run this code

```
    cp c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\fonts\enc\ttf2pk\base\T1-WGL4.enc .
    ttf2tfm chevara.ttf -q -T T1-WGL4.enc -v chevara.vpl recchevara.tfm > chevara.map
    vptovf chevara.vpl ecchevara.vf ecchevara.tfm
    mv chevara.map c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\map\local\
    mv chevara.ttf c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\local\
    mv *.tfm c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\tfm\local\
    mv ecchevara.vf c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\vf\local\
    mktexlsr
    updmap-sys --force --enable Map=chevara.map
    mktexlsr
    pdftex testfont
```

Here the output with `recchevara`:

```
Name of the font to test = recchevara
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\bye
[1{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]<c:/texlive/20
23/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on testfont.pdf (1 page, 12168 bytes).
Transcript written on testfont.log.
```

The same with `ecchevara`

An experiment with other fonts or*

```
ttf2tfm chevara.ttf -q -T T1-WGL4.enc -v chevara.vpl ecchevara.tfm >> chevara.map
```

*replace recchevara.tfm with ecchevara.tfm

produced the same result: The generated testfont.pdf contains a standard font instead of chevara.
What do I have to do differently?

Comment: Why not just use `lualatex`, it can use the font directly, no need to do any extra configuration og re-encoding. See the `fontspec` package.

Comment: lualatex worked, but I would like to know how it works with pdfLaTeX. First of all it's about know-how and in the end also about keeping several options open.

Comment: you must type a command at the prompt e.g. \sample and then the \bye

Comment: It is _much harder_ and in general impossible to use a truetype font with pdflatex. If you have lualatex installed why do you want to do this? a truetype font can have thousands of characters and complicated shaping rules, pdftex fonts can have at most 256 characters and basic ligatures. So (in general) you need to split up the truetype font into tens of separate pdftex fonts and have complicated tex macro support mapping which character ended up in which font.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - !pdfTeX error: pdftex.exe (file Encoding=T1-WGL4.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading

Comment: the enc-file should normally be found (on my system it is found). What is the content of the map file?

Comment: @David Carlisle - This is a font with about 220 characters

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - recchevara   chevara.ttf Encoding=T1-WGL4.enc

Comment: What does `kpsewhich T1-WGL4.enc` return?

Comment: I'd have expected a reencoding line, though.

Comment: `kpsewhich T1-WGL4.enc` -> .T1-WGL4.enc

Comment: Not exactly on-topic, but related: When you change the filename of a font file, it does not change the internal name of the font. So if you ask for "chevara.ttf" as a filename, that is one thing. But if you ask for the "Chavara" (or "chevara") font, that means something different.

Comment: You can not add such an entry to the pdftex.map. Try with a map entry that looks like this `recchevara recchevara " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc <<chevara.ttf` (and remove the wrong one first).

Comment: Now I get a different error. At the moment I have no more time and can only continue tomorrow.
Thank you very much for now.